# On updating shows message: Save or drop changes or copy to clipboard

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was asked to capture the date when a specific field is updated , so I created an event to update the record of that field.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim LDate As String
LDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "UPDATE [Lotinfo] " & _
         "SET [PriorityChanged] = " & _
         Chr(34) & LDate & Chr(34) & _
         " where [BKPO#] = " & _
         Chr(34) & Forms![LotTabFrm]![LotInfoPriority]![BKPO#] & Chr(34) & _
         " and [ModelNo] = " & _
         Chr(34) & Forms![LotTabFrm]![LotInfoPriority]![ModelNo] & Chr(34)
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

The update does happen, however it keeps showing a 'copy to clipboard' message box asking me to drop the changes or copy to clipboard and in both cases the changes are lost

Is there a way to stop that message box from showing up?

Comment: Can you update the question with your version of Access and which type of backend you use (Access tables, SQL server,...)? It might have got something to do with that combination, you can already check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280730/en-us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this message because Ms Access has a conflict. Should it save the values you entered into the form or rather the values you are entering now using the `UPDATE` statement?

Assuming that you want the values from the `UPDATE` statement, add the following line before the `UPDATE` to save the Form values first:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```